# Token indices sequence length warning while using pretrained Roberta model for sentiment analysis

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, roberta-language-model, roberta

I am presently using a pretrained Roberta model to identify the sentiment scores and categories for my dataset. I am truncating the length to 512 but I still get the warning. What is going wrong here? I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from scipy.special import softmax
model = f"j-hartmann/sentiment-roberta-large-english-3-classes"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model, model_max_length=512,truncation=True)
automodel = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model)
```

The warning that I am getting here:

```
Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this model (627 > 512). Running this sequence through the model will result in indexing errors
```

Comment: if you just want to disable that warning then use this ```transformers.utils.logging.set_verbosity_error()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shared the code where you use tokenizer to encode/tokenize the inputs, so I'm taking my own example to explain how you can achieve this.

```
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path,model_max_length=512)
```

example usage:

```
text = "hello "*513 # example text with more than 512 words

tokenizer(text, max_length=512, truncation=True, padding='max_length')

# you may use tokenizer.encode_plus() or tokenizer.encode() based on your need with same parameters to get similar length tokens i.e 512
```

These above parameters will tokenize any string into `max_length` tokens by padding (if number of tokens is < `max_length`)  or truncating (for tokens count > `max_length`).

**Note**: `max_length` cannot be greater than `512` for RoBERTa model.